# pony doesn't send email to gmail address?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pony

I've got an entry form that asks for a persons name and email address. I save that email address to the session so I can access it after the form has been submitted. Then I use Pony to send a thank you/notification email to the person who submitted the form. However, while it sends without issue to a MobileMe address, it won't to a gmail address. The line I'm using to send is:

```
Pony.mail(:to => "#{@email}", :from => 'from@email.com', :subject => "Thanks for entering!", 
:body => "Thank you!")
```

The @email variable is defined in the handler and gets the value from the session.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Here's the helper method I use that uses Pony to send email using `sendmail` when in development on my Mac or via `sendgrid` on `Heroku` when in production.  This works reliably and all of my test emails get sent to my various gmail addresses.

Possibly your problem is that your `from` address is invalid and Google is flagging that as spam. Also I note you are not setting the `Content-Type` header, which is typically `text/html` in my case.

```
def send_email(a_to_address, a_from_address , a_subject, a_type, a_message)
  begin
    case settings.environment
    when :development                          # assumed to be on your local machine
      Pony.mail :to => a_to_address, :via =>:sendmail,
        :from => a_from_address, :subject => a_subject,
        :headers => { 'Content-Type' => a_type }, :body => a_message
    when :production                         # assumed to be Heroku
      Pony.mail :to => a_to_address, :from => a_from_address, :subject => a_subject,
        :headers => { 'Content-Type' => a_type }, :body => a_message, :via => :smtp,
        :via_options => {
          :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
          :port => 25,
          :authentication => :plain,
          :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
          :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
          :domain => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN'] }
    when :test
      # don't send any email but log a message instead.
      logger.debug "TESTING: Email would now be sent to #{to} from #{from} with subject #{subject}."
    end
  rescue StandardError => error
    logger.error "Error sending email: #{error.message}"
  end
end
```